# maximum number of parameters are used in particular procedure in pl sql oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

How many maximum number of parameters are passed to pl/sql procedure. This is my last interview question. I searched lot of sites but all are different answers.

Answer (score 7):

> " I searched lot of sites but all are different answers."

The first place to look for such things is the Oracle documentation. PL/SQL Limits are in [Appendix C of the PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/limits.htm#LNPLS018).

Where we find that

> number of formal parameters in an explicit cursor, function, or procedure: 65536

That is, approximately 65500 more parameters than any sensible design would have.

Comment: im a beginner in oracle, any restriction for maximum in and out parameter in procedure??

Comment: @manikandans - there are no restrictions as such. Like a lot of design decisions it's a matter of style, taste and/or intuition. Lots of parameters - especially if many of them are optional - may indicate that a procedure is responsible for too much and maybe should be decomposed into smaller procs. But it's a judgment.